# Replace a hard-coded text in xslt file with an auto-increment value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following markup snippet in xsl file :

```
<xsl:text>Number of transactions completed;</xsl:text>
```

**Note:** The `<xsl:text>Number of transactions completed;</xsl:text>` is not present in the initial XML file, it has been added in the xsl file.

The above logic generates an XML file which is then converted in `ASCII` file using `XslCompiledTransform`.

The output of the `ASCII` file is the following:

**Iteration 1**

```
AA;Number of transactions completed;
AZ;
```

**Iteration 2**

```
AA;Number of transactions completed;
AZ;
```

**Iteration 3**

```
AA;Number of transactions completed;
AZ;
```

**Iteration 4**

```
AA;Number of transactions completed;
AZ;
```

What I want to achieve is to replace the `Number of transactions completed;` defined in the xls file by an auto-increment number.

Consequently, I want the output of the `ASCII` file to be as follows, with the `Number of transactions completed;` being replaced by the an auto-increment value.  The expected result is shown below.

```
AA;1;
AZ;

AA;2;
AZ;

AA;3;
AZ;

AA;4;
AZ;
```

Could someone please advise on how can I achieve this ?

**EDIT**

Here is the `xslt` I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="Activite/Transaction">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>        
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Date,';')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Time,';')"/>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>    
            <xsl:variable name="j" select="position()" />
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="$j"/>
            </xsl:copy>                                         
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AZ;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Time"/>


            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Date,';')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Time,';')"/>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AZ;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Time"/>


            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Date,';')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Time,';')"/>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AZ;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Time"/>


            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Date,';')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Time,';')"/>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AZ;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Time"/>


            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Date,';')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Time,';')"/>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AZ;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Time"/>

        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>  
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is what I am using to increment the counter.

```
        <xsl:variable name="j" select="position()" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j"/>
        </xsl:copy>
```

*Incrementing by 1*

```
        <xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>
```

I still cannot find a proper solution.
Thank you for your help.

**EDIT 2**

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Activity>
  <Header>
    <Date>2012-12-13</Date>
    <Time>12:12:12</Time>
  </Header>
  <Transaction>
    <Date>2012-12-20</Date>
    <Time>12:12:10</Time>
    <Train>
      <Provider>255</Provider>
      <Tariff>065000</Tariff>
      <StartDate>2012-12-13</StartDate>
      <EndDate>2018-12-01</EndDate>
      <Credit>500</Credit>
      <Persons>500</Persons>
      <Tickets>1000</Tickets>
      <Available>500</Available>
      <Price>2000</Price>
      <TVA>100</TVA>
    </Train>
  </Transaction>
  <Signature xmlns1="str1234">
 <SignatureValue>Wildchild Signature</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</Activity>
```

As we can see the `Number of transactions completed` is not found in the initial file, it has been added in the xsl file after each cycle of transaction `AA to AZ`.

The `current output` I am getting after the conversion to `ASCII` is the following :

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gcjF.png)

Here is the ***expected output*** i wanted :

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En7j0.png)

Thank you for your help and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Are you performing the XSLT transform multiple times to produce multiple files, or are you producing a single ouptut with `AA;xxx;` listed multiple times?

Comment: A single ouptut with `AA;xxx;` listed multiple times.

Comment: Can you show your current XSLT please? It probably just needs to be tweaked to make use of the `position()` function, or maybe `xsl:number`. Thanks!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VT1x6Yrj

Comment: Unfortunately the XSLT in that pastebin is not well-formed. It might help if you edited your question to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry sir, My bad. @TimC
I updated the question with all the required information.
Thank you for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: You are getting there, but you should also show a sample of your XML, and the exact output you want for that XML. Thanks!

Comment: Updated as required Sir,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `<xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>` does not increment the variable `$j` by one. It is calculating the value of 1 added to the value of `$j` and displaying the result. In XSLT variables are immutable, and cannot be updated after being set. `xsl:value-of` does not change anything, it simply displays the result of an expression.

So, rather than repeat `<xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>` multiple times, you need to use `<xsl:value-of select="$j+2"/>`, `<xsl:value-of select="$j+3"/>`, etc

Try this XSLT for starters (which I have shortened, just to make it readable)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <xsl:for-each select="Activity/Transaction">
            <xsl:variable name="j" select="position()" />

            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>    
            <xsl:value-of select="$j"/>

            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j+2"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j+3"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

            <xsl:text>AA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Transaction Number in XML File;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$j+4"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>  
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that if you have multiple `transaction` elements in your XML, and want to carry on the numbering at 6, 7, 8, etc, change the definition of the `$j` variable to this

```
 <xsl:variable name="j" select="position() * 5 - 4" />
```

(Also note, your XSLT was referring to `Activite/Transaction` but in your XML the node was named `Activity`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this `Activite/Transaction`. 
I used `<xsl:variable name="j" select="position() * 5 - 4" />` but to no avail. 


Is there a dynamic way of incrementing the count without having to write 
`<xsl:value-of select="$j+1"/>`, 
`<xsl:value-of select="$j+2"/>`,
`<xsl:value-of select="$j+3"/>`, each time?
Thank you for your prompt answer.

Comment: See an example of the code in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yj. If you could use XSLT 2.0 then you could do `<xsl:for-each select="1 to 5">`. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2m

Comment: Thank you very much sir. The `<xsl:for-each select="1 to 5">` did the trick.